# 301 redirect from URL with query string to new domain with different query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

I am trying to figure out how to do a 301 redirect in my htaccess file to redirect some files to a new domain. Here's what I need to know how to do:

OLD URL: http://www.example.com/index.php?page=news&id=2366

NEW URL: http://www.example2.com/news.php?name=23546

The redirects don't have to be automatically created. I can hard-code the pages I need to redirect in the htaccess file, I just don't know the format to use as I've read that a "standard" 301 redirect won't work with query strings.

Basically this is what I want to do, but from my research so far it doesn't sound like it can be done this way.

```
redirect 301 /index.php?page=news&id=2366 http://www.example2.com/news.php?name=23546
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a rewrite rule with a query string match condition, such as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/index.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^page=news&id=2366$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/news.php?name=23546   [R=301,L]
```

Checkout [this blog page](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/) for more information on how this works.

Comment: I had the same problem - I'm curious why the simple redirect 301 ... doesn't work as it seems it should according to all my googling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but still more complicated, because I needed to discard other parameters.

Like this: `my-old-page.php?a=1&b=2&c=3`

I need to use one of the strings and discard the others, but that solution only worked if I want to use the last parameter (c=3). If I want to use any other (a=1 or b=2) it runs to a 404. After much struggling and searching, I found an answer:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^.* ?b=2.* ?$ (without space after the *)

RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.my-webpage.php/new-location-2?  [R=301,L]
```

The solution is to add `".*?"` before and after the parameter to use.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works.