# htaccess redirects are "ignored"

Tags: .htaccess

Have looked at all the other posts regarding this, but can't seem to get it to work. There are a number of unrelated reasons why I can't change the Joomla config, items, etc., but in any event, it seems that these should work regardless of that.

In short, I want *any* link with *Itemid=30* in it to redirect to the one given.  What am I doing wrong?  The first 3 are what I've tried, that last line is one that is working.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^Itemid=30$ http://inside.beta.oursite.com/index.php?option=com_cware&view=courses&Itemid=125

redirect 301 index.php?option=com_cware&view=courses&Itemid=30 http://inside.beta.oursite.com/index.php?option=com_cware&view=courses&Itemid=125

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=30
RewriteRule ^Itemid=30/$ index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=106&Itemid=121 [R=301]


# If query string contains "username=admin"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} username=admin
# Block it without mercy
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: I've found a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135702/301-redirect-from-url-with-query-string-to-new-domain-with-different-query-strin , but don't understand why the redirect 301 .... doesn't work as I understand that it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) considers only URL paths, which excludes the query string. If you want to take the query string into account, you must employ [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Same applies to [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

Therefore, if you want to match some query string and redirect all URLs to some other URL, use a RewriteCond in combination with RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=30
RewriteRule .* index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=106&Itemid=121 [R=301]
```

This redirects any URL `.*` with the query string containing `Itemid=30` to `index.php?option=com_content&...`