# URL redirect with query strings - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

This is really bugging me, I have followed a few tutorials but just can't get anywhere. I'm trying to do a 301 redirect from:

```
/webpage-mackay.php?wp=Mission
```

to:

```
http://domain.org.au/webpage.php?wp=Mackay%20Mission
```

I have attempted writing like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wp=Mission$
RewriteRule ^/webpage-mackay\.php$ http://domain.org.au/webpage.php?wp=Mackay%20Mission [R=301,L]
```

and:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/webpage-mackay.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^wp=Mission$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://domain.org.au/webpage.php?wp=Mackay%20Mission   [R=301,L]
```

But the result is:

```
http://domain.org.au/webpage.php?wp=Mission
```

Am I missing something? I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135702/301-redirect-from-url-with-query-string-to-new-domain-with-different-query-strin) and [this](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/) as a reference

Comment: browsers may cache the 301 responses. So buggy response maybe cached.

Comment: I tried in another browser and on another server and still get the same result.

Comment: the only reason I see is another redirect directive like `Redirect` in the config or htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems with your first attempt : there is no need for the leading slash in the RewriteRule, and the %20 doesn't work as "%" is a special character.
Here what you can try :

```
# Solution 1 : with a space character in the final URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wp=Mission$
RewriteRule ^webpage-mackay\.php$ http://domain.org.au/webpage.php?wp=Mackay\ Mission [R=301,L]

# Solution 2 : with the %20 in the final URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wp=Mission$
RewriteRule ^webpage-mackay\.php$ http://domain.org.au/webpage.php?wp=Mackay\%20Mission [R=301,L,NE]
```