# redirect URLs with query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to add redirect from page http://www.mysite.ru/news/?PAGEN_1=1 to http://www.mysite.ru/news/, so I added in .htaccess file code below

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/ [R=301,L]
```

but I get error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Already asked refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135702/301-redirect-from-url-with-query-string-to-new-domain-with-different-query-strin

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^PAGEN_1=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ http://www.mysite.ru/news/$ [R=301,L]
```