# How to redirect 301 this link (https://www.example.com/?lang=en) into this link (https://www.example2.com/en/)?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to do a redirect 301 from this links in my .htaccess file.

Old url: https://www.example.com/?lang=en

New url: https://www.example2.com/en/

I'll try to use this instruction:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=en$

RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /en/     [R=301,L]
```

like answer of this question ([301 redirect from URL with query string to new domain with different query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135702/301-redirect-from-url-with-query-string-to-new-domain-with-different-query-strin)), but my result is this: https://www.example2.com/en/?lang=en.

How can i remove the querystring "?lang=en" and obtain the new url?

Now it works with add the flag QSD, but now i've this problem:

I need to redirect this links too :

Old url 2: https://www.example.com/?lang=de

New url 2: https://www.example2.com/de/

And this links:

Old url 3: https://www.example.com/?lang=ru

New url 3: https://www.example2.com/ru/

If i use the instruction above, changing the query string, the redirect doesn't work for all of the language.

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=en$

RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /en/     [R=301,L,QSD]



RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=de$

RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /de/     [R=301,L,QSD]



RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=ru$

RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /ru/     [R=301,L,QSD]
```

How can i resolve this new problem?

**EDIT 2:**

Solution for @QuickBecko

There are two solutions, depending on the Apache version:

**First solution**

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=en$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /en/     [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=de$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /de/     [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=ru$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /ru/     [R=301,L,QSD]
```

**Second solution**

```
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=en$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /en/?     [R=301,L]
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=de$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /de/?     [R=301,L]
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^lang=ru$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /ru/?     [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Read the documentation, I would suggest. I clearly points out the `QSD` flag you want to use here...

Comment: Or you can use a `?` (a question Mark) to remove the old querystring , `RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   /en/?    [R=301,L]`

Comment: Works with QSD, but now i have a new problem, i edit the answer

Comment: for updated one, you dont need `RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/$` for each one just keep one on the top than remove the others

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive thank you a lot, it works now, thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will do the job:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example2.com/en/?  [R=301,L]
```

Basically if you add `?` at the end it will remove the query from the link.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Kindly, please accept the answer if this answer works for you.

Comment: @AlessioPuccini Hello, i have a same problem, but when i add this code in `.htaccess`, page shows `error 404`, how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @QuickBecko edit the question with the solutions, try to use one of them